# Remove urls that have certain domain in them

Tags: php, regex

I have a set of urls for example

- http://t3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRfLZhH0jpyUJxGtsiHcldUPiNQsosLdR9xgcYqVWyRWGYS4qtt
- http://feeds.feedburner.com/~r/DrudgeReportFeed/~4/zSLWG4ybmjw

I want to remove any url that has feeds.feedburner.com in it. What regular expression would I use? (php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this regexp:

```
/feeds\.feedburner\.com/
```

Answer (score 1):

Why use regex? Use [`parse_url`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php).

```
$urlData = parse_url($url);
if ($urlData['host'] != 'feeds.feedburner.com'){
  // Not a feedburner url
}
```

Shorthand, by the way, is as follows:

```
if (parse_url($url, PHP_URL_HOST) != 'feeds.feedburner.com'){
  // same outcome
}
```

Comment: +1 for `parse_url`, I don't know why people are so obsessed with regex, everyone use them everywhere...